# How to animate TextBlock when its value changes in WinRT XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have the following `Storyboard`

```
<Storyboard x:Name="DeleteStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="StatusTextBlock">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

and the following `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="StatusTextBlock" Text="{Binding Status}">
```

Both are in `SettingsFlyout` not a `Page`.

I want the `Storyboard` to start when the `TextBlock` value changes.

I'm using MVVM, so please no code-behind stuff unless absolutely necessary.

I tries searching for hints and tried different combination of `Behaviors`, `Triggers` and `VisualState` but reached nowhere.

Comment: I am sorry, but your requirements are conflicting. UI manipulations and animations should be managed in code-behind. The fact that you are managing your data with MVVM does not change this. MVVM intentionally removes the reference of the view from the view model. If you include the requirement for animations of "no code behind stuff" I am afraid you have already broken the core concept of the design patterns are not asking for something that really makes sense. Not that it can't be done. But your requirement implies the pattern, but then negates it. Not sure if an answer is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @JerryNixon-MSFT. I guess we agree in general. In my question I was trying to avoid answers which I can find in MSDN code samples; like handling event, manipulate data, then call `MyStoryboard.Begin()`, all in code-behind. My app executes a command in response to a button press, do stuff in ViewModel, then report the status to the view using `Status` property. At this point I want to animate the `TextBlock`. I know that the operation completed and the status of it from the `Status` property. In short, get the status and animate. Does this make more sense and changes the answer?

Comment: Use behaviors. I think that's best for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Again, not sure if we are 100% agreeing. But, still, here's how you can do it:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public void Loaded()
{
    var myBox = new TextBox();
    var myAni = new Storyboard();
    var MyVvm = new MyViewModel();

    // sensible approach
    myBox.TextChanged += (s, e) => myAni.Begin();

    // forced approach
    MyVvm.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Text"))
            myAni.Begin();
    };
}
```

In the end, you are the developer of your own app. not me.

If you are willing to use behaviors, you can also do the same thing this way:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeAway">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="textBox">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeAway}"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

I suppose you can have your "pure" MVVM approach using a behavior. It gets you 100% XAML, and that makes some developers feel warm and fuzzy; I get that. And, I like behaviors. Look. I don't want to argue with you here, it's just that the top approach is certainly not "wrong".

> Learn more about behaviors: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/10/everything-i-know-about-behaviors-in.html

Best of luck.

Comment: Two good approaches presented, thanks Jerry. I also liked your comments on devs wanting to feel warm and fuzzy. :)

Comment: @Jerry , I noticed how you used a `Textbox` instead of a `TextBlock`. Is there any way to get the same functionality on a `TextBlock` instead using behaviors and propertyChanged event?