# UWP ContentControl not applying ContentThemeTransition

Tags: c#, uwp, transition, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to get a `ContentControl` to apply a `ContentThemeTransition`where the content will be a string, so when the string changes via a binding the new string will animate in. I can't use `ContentThemeTransition` with a `TextBlock` as this doesn't derive from `ContentControl`.

Here is some example XAML that shows the problem. If I edit the text in the Textbox (which represents the text in my ViewModel that the `ContentControl` is really bound to) I would expect the Text shown in the `ContentControl` to animate in, but it doesn't.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>  
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="text" Text="Hello" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    <ContentControl  Grid.Row="1" Width="100"  Height="100" Content="{Binding ElementName=text , Path=Text}">
        <ContentControl.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <ContentThemeTransition HorizontalOffset="40"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </ContentControl.Transitions>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I am getting somewhere now. If you replace the `ContentControl` XAML to

```
<ContentPresenter Background="Black" Foreground="Red"  Grid.Row="1" Width="100"  Height="100" Content="{Binding ElementName=text , Path=Text}">
        <ContentPresenter.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <ContentThemeTransition VerticalOffset="-100"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </ContentPresenter.ContentTransitions>
    </ContentPresenter>
```

then it works. Oddly, with the VerticalOffset =-100 as above the new value animates down outside of the `ContentControl`i.e. its visible outside the bounds of the control. Anyone know how to change things so the animation only appears within the confines of the `ContentPresenter`?

Answer (score 1):

Tested by my side, your first `<ContentThemeTransition HorizontalOffset="40"/>` and second `<ContentThemeTransition VerticalOffset="-100"/>` both work but only for the first time, you can enlarge the `HorizontalOffset` for testing and check if it works.

Since you expected that the animation should work every time the text is changed, I think you will need to create a animation which targets the `Text` of `TextBlock` directly instead of targeting the `Content` of `ContentControl`.

In this scenario, [XAML Behaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) will be a good helper. You can refer to @Jerry Nixon - MSFT's answer in thread:  [How to animate TextBlock when its value changes in WinRT XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745717/how-to-animate-textblock-when-its-value-changes-in-winrt-xaml)

**Update:**

My mistake that I only noticed that you changed `HorizontalOffset` to `VerticalOffset`. You actually also changed `ContentControl` to `ContentPresenter`.

According to the UI coordinate of UWP, since your animation target the `ContentPresenter`, then consider the left-top point of  your `ContentPresent` is (0, 0). When you set `<ContentThemeTransition VerticalOffset="-100"/>`, it will transit from up (0, -100) back to (0, 0) and it will definitely animate outside of your `ContentPresent`, I think it is designed to be so, and we're not able change it. Here I can only suggest that modifying the transition from down to up like `<ContentThemeTransition VerticalOffset="100"/>`, it will help a little here but eventually it changes your animation, so I don't think this will be a good approach.

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, please see my UPDATE in the original post. If I use `ContentPresenter` then I can get it to work everytime the Text Changes which is great. THe only problem is that if I use `VerticalOffset = -100` then the text visibly floats in from outside the bounds of the  `ContentPresenter` which looks odd.

Comment: @Cleve, My mistake, I only noticed that you changed `HorizontalOffset` to `VerticalOffset`, you actually also changed your animation target. I will update my answer later.

Comment: @Cleve, I've updated my answer, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Hi @Grace Feng, no apologies necessary. Thank you for your help.